# How to override a varible (present in parent class) in child class in java?

Tags: java

// These are my two classes
  TestSetupBAT.java

```
public class TestSetupBAT {  
  public static List<String> uniqueNameFields = new ArrayList<String>();  
}


SmokeTest.java

public class SmokeTest extends TestSetupBAT {
uniqueNameFields.add("welcome"); //throws error
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The question above is not at all clear. What do you want to do to `uniqueNameFields` in SmokeTest? What have you tried to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Do it as follows,
You are trying to access fields and modify it on class level rather it should be done inside a ctor/method.

```
public class TestSetupBAT 
{  
   public static List<String> uniqueNameFields = new ArrayList<String>();  
}


SmokeTest.java

public class SmokeTest extends TestSetupBAT {

  public SmokeTest()
  {
     uniqueNameFields.add("welcome");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> How to override a varible (present in parent class) in child class in
>   java?

`static` fields can't be inherited in Java, so remove `static` for `uniqueNameFields`, if you want to override it in your subclass i.e., `SmokeTest`.

Also, your `uniqueNameFields.add("welcome");` code does not belong to any block (like any method, constructor, etc..) i.e., `uniqueNameFields.add("welcome");` statement should be under a constructor or method (shown below) or initialization block.

```
public class TestSetupBAT {  
  protected List<String> uniqueNameFields = new ArrayList<String>();  
}

public class SmokeTest extends TestSetupBAT {  

  //override uniqueNameFields
  proectected List<String> uniqueNameFields = new ArrayList<String>();  

   public void method1() {

       //"welcome" will be added to overridden uniqueNameFields
       uniqueNameFields.add("welcome");
   }
}
```

Comment: downvoters, please let me know the problem with this